# how to make this function return a string

Tags: c, string

I have this code:

```
static char * display(const u8 array[], int length) {
    int i;
    char *str;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i%32 == 0) {
            //printf("\n");
            strcat(str, "\n");
        }
        if (i%8 == 0) {
            //printf(" ");
            strcat(str, " ");
        }
        //printf("%02X", array[i]);
        strcat(str, (char *)array[i]);
    }
    return str;
    /*
    char str[80];
    strcpy (str,"these ");
    strcat (str,"strings ");
    strcat (str,"are ");
    strcat (str,"concatenated.");
    puts (str);
    return 0;
    */
}
```

Originally this code was printing a string. I dont want it to print a string, I need to make it returning a string. But it gives me this error:

> main.c: In function 'display':
>   main.c:1707:9: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcat' makes pointer
>   from integer without a cast [ena bled by default]
>
> ```
>      strcat(str, array[i]);                                                                      
>      ^                                                                                            In file included from main.c:61:0:
> ```
>
> /usr/include/string.h:133:14: note: expected 'const char *
>   **restrict**' but argument is of type 'u8'  extern char *strcat (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
>                 ^                                                                                       sh-4.2# gcc -o main *.c
>   main.c: In function 'display':
>   main.c:1707:21: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different
>   size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
>            strcat(str, (char *)array[i]);

EDIT:

build shared object and load:

```
VALUE generateIt(char *valor) {
  struct NESSIEstruct w;
  u8 digest[DIGESTBYTES];

  int i;
  for(i=0; valor[i]!='\0'; ++i);
  int sizeo = i;

  NESSIEinit(&w);
  NESSIEadd((u8*)valor, 8*sizeo, &w);
  NESSIEfinalize(&w, digest);
  return displayIt(digest, DIGESTBYTES);
}
```

on top I do:

```
#include 'ruby.h'
```

and I add also this:

```
void
Init_whirlpool(){
  rb_mWhirlpool = rb_define_module("Whirlpool");
  rb_cClass = rb_define_class_under(rb_mWhirlpool, "Class", rb_cObject);
  rb_define_method(rb_cClass, "generate", generateIt, 1);
}
```

Comment: Well, a `u8` is obviously not the right type.

Comment: `str` is an uninitialized pointer that will have an undefined value. Probably going to crash when you use it.

Comment: @iharob 

* u8   -> unsigned integer type, at least 8 bits, equivalent to unsigned char

Comment: @PSantos What is `VALUE` is it a generic type used by `ruby`? something like `void *`? I am almost sure the problem is you need to use some ruby custom memory allocation funciton that lets the interpreter handle memory allocation. And where did you add the `free`?

Comment: @iharob

In Ruby C API, every Ruby type/class is a VALUE C type. In fact VALUE is a just a uintptr_t C type, or void* to simplify things. This is how Ruby’s loose typing is implemented in C.

Comment: @PSantos So where did you add the `free`? or the crash is happening without `free`?

Comment: @PSantos apparently you need to return the value with `Data_Wrap_Struct(rb_cClass, NULL, free, str);`, instead of just `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you need

```
static char *display(const unsigned char array[], int length)
{
    int  i, k;
    char *str;

    str = malloc(3 * length + 1);
    if (str == NULL)
        return NULL;
    k      = 0;
    str[0] = '\0';
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char hex[3];

        if (i % 32 == 0)
            str[k++] = '\n';
        if (i % 8 == 0)
            str[k++] = ' ';
        snprintf(hex, sizeof(hex), "%02X", array[i]);

        str[k++] = hex[0];
        str[k++] = hex[1];
    }
    str[k] = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

`snprintf` is POSIX, if it gives a compilation error, change it to `_snprintf`.

And don't forget to `free` the returned value in the caller function.

Comment: All `int`s here really should be `size_t`s.

Comment: @alk sometimes when I use `size_t` the OP's ask something like, `What is size_t?`.

Comment: Then tell him/her? However, `unsigned` would at least be obvious.

Comment: @alk Oh i've told them, but then they would say something like Oh no, that's too advanced I will just use `int`.

Comment: A `signed` variable simply makes **no** sense to count an amount of memory or to measure the length of a "string".

Comment: However sometimes functions that return counts of things, can return `int`'s and precisely because there no negative count of things, because then, returning a negative value could be used as an error value. Not this case of course, here you are totally right.

Comment: For this we have `ssize_t`! :-)

Comment: @iharob sorry my ignorance. You said to call free. But I dont know where to do it. 

I am trying to call a C function on a Ruby code. Now I am getting a error: "[BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13 revision 48408) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0]"

I think that it is about the memory

Comment: How do you call the c function from ruby? is there a wrapper like ctypes for python? or you build a shared object and load it in ruby?

Comment: build shared object and load:

```
VALUE generateIt(char *valor) {
  struct NESSIEstruct w;
  u8 digest[DIGESTBYTES];

  int i;
  for(i=0; valor[i]!='\0'; ++i);
  int sizeo = i;

  NESSIEinit(&w);
  NESSIEadd((u8*)valor, 8*sizeo, &w);
  NESSIEfinalize(&w, digest);
  return displayIt(digest, DIGESTBYTES);
}
```

on top I do:

```
#include 'ruby.h'
```

and I add also this:

```
void
Init_whirlpool(){
  rb_mWhirlpool = rb_define_module("Whirlpool");
  rb_cClass = rb_define_class_under(rb_mWhirlpool, "Class", rb_cObject);
  rb_define_method(rb_cClass, "generate", generateIt, 1);
}
```

Comment: @PSantos please add the code to the question as an edit.